# Is this set of event axioms complete?

Tags: probability-theory, axioms

In the notes' first chapter of the course ["Discrete Stochastic Processes"](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/index.htm) presented by Prof. Robert Gallager, the "Axioms for events" defined as follows:

> **1.2.1 Axioms for events** [[Chapter 1: Introduction and review of probability, page 6]](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap01.pdf)
>
> Given a sample space $\Omega$ , the class of subsets of $\Omega$ that constitute the set of events satisfies
>   the following axioms:
>
> 1. $\Omega$ is an event.
> 2. For every sequence of events $A_1, A_2, \ldots$, the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is an event.
> 3. For every event $A$, the complement $A^c$ is an event.

The notes also states that:

> Note that the axioms do not say that all subsets of $\Omega$ are events. In fact, there are many rather silly ways to define classes of events that obey the axioms.

Based on aforementioned axioms I cannot find any event except $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$.

For example, suppose we have $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}$, is $A=\{1\}$ an event? If answer is yes, based on which axioms?

Comment: "the class of subsets of $\Omega$", so I would think that if $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$, then yes.

Comment: So essentially you say every subset of $\Omega$ is an event?

Comment: Those conditions looks consistent but not complete. I.e. they look like they are necessary for any characterisation of events but not sufficient to define all events.

Comment: As I understand it, $A$ needs to be in $\Omega$, and it also needs to be in the subset of $\Omega$ which represent the set of events.

Comment: You are correct in that only $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ can be deduced as being events from these axioms. In fact, from only axioms $1$ and $3$.

Comment: The class of subsets of $\Omega$ that constitute the set of events satisfies those axioms. Provided $\Omega$ has more than one element, more than one such class can be selected for a given $\Omega$. The smallest one is $\{ \Omega,\emptyset \}$; the largest one is $P(\Omega)$ (the set of all subsets of $\Omega$). Most of the time we deal with a set of events which is in between these two extremes. (Actually, most of the time we don't deal directly with the set of events at all.)

Comment: @Ian, Your statement is not true, based on what in this notes, there are subsets of $\Omega$  that are not events.In the notes of the course we see: "Note that the axioms do not say that all subsets of $\Omega$ are events. In fact, there are many
rather silly ways to define classes of events that obey the axioms."

Comment: @T.Rahgooy You misunderstand me; I said "the class of subsets of $\Omega$ that constitute..." not "the class of subsets of $\Omega$ constitutes..." Rephrasing: the set of events in a probability space is *some* collection of subsets of the sample space $\Omega$, satisfying the three axioms you've given. If $\Omega$ has more than one element, then there are multiple ways to define a set of events from $\Omega$. The smallest one is $\{ \Omega,\emptyset \}$; the largest one is $P(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Ian, $P(\Omega)$ may not satisfy the axioms when $\Omega$ is not finite set, I say this based on what the notes says. But as I understand from your comment, you say we choose collection of subsets of $\Omega$ and assume all elements of this subset are events, then we apply the axioms to the collection, if it passes the axioms, we say this collection is a valid event set, right?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy $P(\Omega)$ will always satisfy the axioms, since any countable union or complement of a set (relative to $\Omega$) is a subset of $\Omega$. Anyway, yes, that is a way of putting it.

Comment: @Ian, Can you explain how for $\Omega = [1,2]$ , $P(\Omega)$ satisfies the axioms?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy The situation is the same for any set: the union (countable or otherwise, it doesn't matter) of a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ is a subset of $\Omega$, and the complement (relative to $\Omega$) of a subset of $\Omega$ is a subset of $\Omega$. Finally $\Omega$ itself is a subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: $\Omega = [1,2]$ is not countable and therefore the $P(\Omega)$ is not countable, am I wrong?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy You are right that $P([1,2])$ is not countable. But what in the axioms says that a set of events must be countable? Note that this is not merely a pointless exercise; the underlying $\sigma$-algebra behind a uniform distribution on an interval is indeed uncountable.

Comment: @Ian, I say there are uncountable sets in $P([1,2])$ which can not be said that are events, because they are not satisfying the axioms.

Comment: @T.Rahgooy The elements of $P([1,2])$ needn't satisfy the axioms, just $P([1,2])$ itself satisfies the axioms. And it does: $[1,2]$ is a subset of $[1,2]$, so it is in $P([1,2])$. If $A$ is a subset of $[1,2]$, then $A^c=[1,2] \setminus A$ is also a subset of $[1,2]$, so $A^c$ is in $P([1,2])$. Finally if you have *any* collection of subsets (not necessarily countable in this case) of $[1,2]$, their union is a subset of $[1,2]$, so it is in $P([1,2])$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ian, I gained some insight to the subject through you useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection of events satisfying axioms 1-3 is called a $\sigma$-algebra. You, no doubt, encountered this in the context of probability space 
$$(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$$
where the second member of the tiple $\mathcal{A}$, the collection of events on which the probability measure $P$ is defined, must be a $\sigma$-algebra. Both $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ and $2^{\Omega}$, the set of all subsets of $\Omega$, are examples of $\sigma$-algebras. But, between these two extremes, there are many more $\sigma$-algebras, and you have to choose one of them to be your set of events, when you define a probability space.

When $\Omega$ is finite, you will usually choose $2^{\Omega}$ for your set of events. But, when $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, it turns out that there is, for example, no probability measure defined on the whole $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $P(\{x\})=0$ for every singleton $\{x\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and if we are interested in such measures, we have to restrict our attention to some smaller $\sigma$-algebra of events, that will make it possible to define such a probability measure. In case of $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ it will usually be the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

In short, you choose the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable events so that it is small enough to enable us to define a desired probability measure on it, and large enough to encompass all the sets we are interested in. In principle, it will vary from probability space to probability space.

Comment: You can put a probability measure on $2^\Omega$ for uncountable $\Omega$. For instance take a countable subset, pick your favorite probability measure to put on the subset, and assign probability zero to any set disjoint from this subset. You can't put a translation-invariant measure on $2^{\mathbb{R}}$, but that's another story entirely.

Comment: @Ian Yes, thank you. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The axioms are right, and one cannot say that $A = \{1\}$ is an event.

It may be that your $\sigma$-algebra of events is simply $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$.

So to answer the exercise, one should say: "Based on the axioms one cannot say whether $A$ is an event".